# MySQL Inverse Select Result from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables I want to find the unmatch results :

```
    table1

    REF    CARD   AMOUNT
    12345  55432  1000
    23456  55321  2000
    34567  55789  3000


    table2

    MSG                AMT    ID
    12345_T1R3-55432   1000   456
    23456-R1M5-55321   2000   567
    34567*O1L@-13123   5000   783
```

My Query :

```
SELECT
  'table1'.'REFF',
  'table2'.'MSG',
  'table1'.'card',
  'table1'.`amount`,
  'table2'.'amt'
FROM
  'table1',
  'table2'
WHERE
  'table2'.'MSG' LIKE CONCAT('%', 'table1'.'REFF', '%') AND 'table2'.'MSG' LIKE CONCAT('%', 'table1'.'card', '%')
```

QUERY RESULT

```
table1.reff    table2.msg          table1.card   table1.amount   table2.amt
12345          12345_T1R3-55432    55432         1000            1000
23456          23456-R1M5-55321    55321         2000            2000
```

I want to get the other result (inverse) from this result like :

```
table1.reff    table2.msg          table1.card   table1.amount   table2.amt
34567          34567*O1L@-13123    55789         3000            5000
```

Thank you

Comment: Your use of single quotes is totally incorrect.

Comment: I was using MySQL Front, and the app gave the quotes automatically

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of `P And Q` is `not P or not Q`.  So applying this to your query yields:

```
SELECT
    t1.REFF,
    t1.MSG,
    t1.card,
    t1.amount,
    t2.amt,
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.MSG LIKE CONCAT('%', t1.REFF, '%') AND
       t2.MSG LIKE CONCAT('%', t1.card, '%')
WHERE
    t2.MSG IS NULL;
```

By the way, your use of single quotes is totally incorrect.  The query you posted would probably not even run, so I am guessing that perhaps you copied it wrongly.

Comment: Thank you, but the result I'm getting from this query is the same with adding NOT before the LIKE query

Comment: The query was taking too long, so I restarted MySQL services, and got the current results, but the t2.MSG value is NULL. Can I have MSG field not showing NULL? Thank you

Comment: @Andy Please edit your question and show sample data and expected output.  My answer is reasonable given what little information you gave us.